# Why independent events are never mutually exclusive?

Tags: probability

I am a novice at probability and I came across this statement in my maths book.
Two independent events are never mutually exclusive. I am not getting why it  is so. Can anyone explain using a ven diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A, B$ are mutually exclusive, and $P(A)>0,P(B)>0$. Then $P(A\cap B)=0$. But if they are independent then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)>0$. Contradicion.

Comment: In other words the claim is justified if both events $A$ and $B$ have positive probability.  But if not (as in Ross's example) the claim may be false.

Comment: @hardmath yes, indeed! For example degenerate at a single point distribution, this will not hold.

Answer (score 2):

It is not strictly true.  If you have two events and A always happens and B never does(or the reverse), they are mutually exclusive because you never have both happen together.  The probability of A does not depend on whether B happens because it is $1$ and similarly the probability of $B$ does not depend on whether A happens because it is $0$.  In a Venn diagram all the events are in the $A \cap \lnot B$ region.

Outside this corner case the statement is true.  If you know A happened you know B did not, so independence is violated.

Comment: Sir, what is $A \cap \lnot B$ (not familiar with the notation!)

Comment: It is the intersection of $A$ and $\lnot B$.  In the standard 2 statement Venn diagram it is the full circle of $A$ less the lens of $A \cap B$.  The answer you accepted assumes $P(A) \gt 0, P(B) \gt 0$.  I am pointing out that if that assumption (which is not part of the question) is violated, the statement is false.

Comment: Also $\neg B$ is the complement of $B$.

Comment: @RossMillikan  thanks.... that is why I put that conditions, as I said in the comment section this will not hold for degenerate at a single point distribution!

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanksssss, I see here people use that notation but did not know the meaning. Every time I see this notation, I skip that post... so at last I had to ask it. Btw why people use that notation... $B^c$ or $B'$ are enough,isn't!!! Is this became useful because of **logic gate** or something like that...

Comment: @MANMAID  Indeed.  Set Operations and Logical Calculus use quite similar symbols, since they are rather closely related concepts.  So the misappropriation of logical-not has become an acceptable notation for set-complementation.